# Create javascript object containing # of days in a given month

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I have the following code, which returns the number of days in a month:

```
daysInMonth(month:number, year:number) {
            return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}
```

Let's say this gives me `31`. Now, in my html, I want to create a `dropdown` element with all the days in the month, listed out in order. So, my dropdown would consist of:

`1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11.....` All the way to `31`.

I need to build this object dynamically since the days in the month will change based on the month.

What's the most efficient way to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by efficient? Efficient would be to have an html select with 31 options, then hide any extras when you select the year and month. And the only month you need to check is february, all the others are always the same, and can be efficiently stored in a array.

Answer (score 1):

I would use jQuery.

So somewhere along the line you'd do something:

```
var dropDown = $('<select/>').appendTo('body');    


for (var i = 1; i <= daysOfMonth; i++) {
    dropDown.append('<option value=' + i + '>' + i + '</option>');
}
```

You would clearly need to get the value of `daysOfMonth` from somewhere previously.

Comment: If you're using Chrome, you could open up the console and try the code on this very page and it'll work (you'll see the drop down at the very bottom of the page). That being said, make sure to define `daysofMonth`with some value greater than 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to achieve the dropdown:

```
(function() {
    var totalDays = daysInMonth(2, 2014),
        selectEl = document.createElement('select');

    for (var i = 1; i <= totalDays; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i));
        option.setAttribute('value', i);
        selectEl.appendChild(option);
    }

    document.body.appendChild(selectEl);
}());
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3mSU2/1/)